# How to get object data when one value is changed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I've certain records of data which are populated in a grid. It also has two input fields one for text and other is date. User can make any changes on text or date field. My concern is that when date value is changed, text data is shown in console along with new date value, but, when text value or date value from other record is changed, the previous record's text value is reset to old value. Please refer to the code below

Below is the code where I'm extracting both text and date values on handlechange

```
const handleChange = (data) => {
    const { id: newId, textVal: franchise, dateVal: dateData } = data;
    setDataNew((prevInfo) => {
      const newList = [...prevInfo];
      const index = newList.findIndex((datum) => datum.newId === newId);
      if (index !== -1) {
        if (newId !== undefined) {
          newList[index].newId = newId;
        }
        if (franchise !== undefined) {
          newList[index].franchise = franchise;
        }
        if (dateData !== undefined) {
          newList[index].dateData = dateData;
        }
      } else {
        newList.push({ newId, franchise, dateData });
      }
      return [...newList];
    });
  };
```

These are the changes

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => textCallback({textVal: e.target.value,id: rowData[0].id,
dateVal: rowData[4] <-- This date value is added in text field
})}/>


<DatePickerNew setRequesterDate={(e) => dateCallback({dateVal: e, id: rowData[0].id,
                                    textVal: rowData[3] <-- This text value is added in date field
                                  })} startDate={colData}
                              />
```

As you can see from above code, new keys have been added to get the values of respective fields. It works for date field but, not for text field. What could be the best optimal solution?

Please refer to codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-dubinsky-7z53vc?file=/src/Grid.js

Do observe the console output to see the changes

Comment: not able to reproduce

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, when date for one record is changed the text value is shown, but when other record's date or text value is changed, previous text data returns to original value...  can you please refer codesandbox